# JSON Data not getting added to DB

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to build a Node API which uses MongoDB to create and fetch information from a file which contains Book information in the following JSON format:

```
{
 Name: String,
 Author: String,
 Price: Number
}
```

I am unable to add info to the DB. I get the Book printed successfully message though. But when I see the DB, a JSON document is created only with an `ID` and the version key `_v`.

Below is my API code:

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser=require('body-parser');
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var book = require('./automobile/reading/book')

//configuring the app for the bosy data intake for post operations
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var PORT= process.env.PORT || 3000;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/helloworldapi');

var router = express.Router();

app.use('/api', router);

router.use(function(req,res,next){
  console.log('There is something happening in the API');
  next();
})

router.route('/books')
  .post(function(req,res){
    var bookDB = new book();
    bookDB.name=req.body.name;
    bookDB.author=req.body.author;
    bookDB.price=req.body.price;

    bookDB.save(function(err){
      if(err){
        res.send(err);
      }
    res.json({message: 'Book was successfully printed'});
    });
  })
  .get(function(req,res){
    book.find(function(err, books){
     if(err){
       res.send(err);
     }
      res.json(books);
    });
  });
  router.route('/books/:book_id')
    .get(function(req,res){
      book.findById(req.params.book_id, function(err, books){
        if(err){
          res.send(err);
        }
          res.json(books)
      });
    });

  router.route('/books/name/:name')
  .get(function(req,res){
    book.find({name:req.params.name}, function(err, books){
      if(err){
        res.send(err);
      }
        res.json(books);
    });
  });

  router.route('/books/author/:author')
   .get(function(req,res){
     book.find({author:req.params.author}, function(err, books){
       if(err){
         res.send(err);
       }
         res.json(books);
     });
   });

app.listen(PORT);
console.log('server listening on port '+PORT);
```

While trying to perform a `GET` Operation after performing the `POST` Operation, I am getting the below response:

```js
[
    {
        "_id": "5a788cf1ad829e3aa4b91287",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

Below is my shema:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var BookSchema = new Schema({
  Name: String,
  Author: String,
  Price: Number 
});

module.exports= mongoose.model('book',BookSchema);
```

Please don't mind the root folder `automobiles`. Planned to create something else in the beginning.

Comment: Show the file referenced by `var book = require('./automobile/reading/book')`.  Specifically, the `save()` method, since it looks like that is what actually writes to the DB.

Comment: Hi @zero298. Thank you for your quick response. I have attached the snapshot for your reference.

Comment: Please post the actual source code and not an image.

Comment: Hi @zero298. I have added the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is because you are not assigning to the right properties.  In your route, you assign to the **lowercase** properties.  However, you Schema defines **uppercase** properties.  See if matching the case works:

```
router.route('/books')
  .post(function(req,res){
    var bookDB = new book();
    bookDB.name=req.body.name; // This needs to match the property in the schema exactly
    bookDB.author=req.body.author;
    bookDB.price=req.body.price;

    bookDB.save(function(err){
      if(err){
        res.send(err);
      }
    res.json({message: 'Book was successfully printed'});
    });
  })

var BookSchema = new Schema({
  name: String, // Now I'm lower case
  author: String,
  price: Number 
});
```

Or you can make your router uppercase:

```
router.route('/books')
  .post(function(req,res){
    var bookDB = new book();
    bookDB.Name=req.body.name;
    bookDB.Author=req.body.author;
    bookDB.Price=req.body.price;

    bookDB.save(function(err){
      if(err){
        res.send(err);
      }
    res.json({message: 'Book was successfully printed'});
    });
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
  router.route('/books')
  .post(function(req,res){
   var bookDB = new book(req.body);

   bookDB.save(function(err){
    if(err){
     res.send(err);
    }
   res.json({message: 'Book was successfully printed'});
  });
})
```

But the req.body values should be same on schema values.